# Laravel SQL Query Exception on Syntax Error

Tags: php, laravel

I set up *marketplacekit* using the installation instruction at https://github.com/marketplacekit/marketplacekit, which is based on Laravel framework. On accessing the index.php, I encountered the error below:

> Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (42000)`   SQLSTATE[42000]:
>   Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
>   version for the right syntax to use near '>'$."price"') as aggregate
>   from 'listings' where 'listings'.'deleted_at' is null" at line 1
>   (SQL: select min('meta'->'$."price"') as aggregate from 'listings'
>   where 'listings'.'deleted_at' is null)

Please help with a resolution for this. Thanks. My PHP version is 7.2.7; Mysql: 15.1; MariaDB: 10.3.10; Apache server 2.4.33

Comment: Have you tried to get it to work on MYSQL there might be a sight difference from MYSQL and MariaDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is a known issue. Apparently Laravel doesn't support JSON where clauses in MariaDB:

https://github.com/marketplacekit/marketplacekit/issues/20

They mentioned this package to add MariaDB support, but had not tested it:

https://github.com/ybr-nx/laravel-mariadb